# PHP using urldecode with regex

Tags: php

I'm trying to use this line of code to accept URL variables with spaces replaced by '%20' but it also has to go through a regex

```
$type=urldecode(ereg_replace("[^a-zA-Z0-9%]+", "", @$_REQUEST['type']));
```

The result is just the %20 removed instead of replacing with a space e.g JohnDoe not John Doe, from John%20Doe

Comment: Your could would replace everything matching by your regex with nothing ("").

Comment: The superglobals $_GET and $_REQUEST are already decoded. Using urldecode() on an element in $_GET or $_REQUEST could have unexpected and dangerous results.

Comment: The answer is

$type=ereg_replace("[^a-zA-Z0-9[:space:][:blank:]]+", "", @$_REQUEST['type']);
As mentioned it has to go through the regex for other reasons, $_REQUEST is decoded by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the order wrong and note that `ereg_replace` is depreciated .. `preg_replace` is a better option

Try

```
 $type  = ereg_replace("[^a-zA-Z0-9%]+", "", urldecode(@$_REQUEST['type']));
```

Better Approch

```
$type = @$_REQUEST['type'] ; 
$type = urldecode($type);
$type = str_replace(" ","",$type) ;
```

Thanks

:)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to replace space with `%20` then use:

```
str_replace(" ", "%20", $_REQUEST['type']);
```

no need to use regex here.

Comment: Wrong parameter order. str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )

Answer (score 0):

`$type = str_replace("%20", "", @$_REQUEST["type"]);` should work and would replace all %20 by "".